# iscsiadm discovery gives this error: "Try `iscsiadm --help' for more information."

Tags: iscsi

Many sets of instructions (e.g. [Softlayer](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/accessing-block-storage-consistent-performance-linux)) provide this command for discovering a new iSCSI device:

```
iscsiadm –m discovery –t sendtargets –p 255.255.255.255
```

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iscsiadm) for iscsiadm gives this command:

```
iscsiadm --mode discoverydb --type sendtargets --portal 255.255.255.255 --discover
```

Both give me this error:

```
Try `iscsiadm --help' for more information.
```

And this exit code, which corresponds to `ISCSI_ERR_INVAL - invalid argument`:

```
# echo $?
7
```

I'm using this version of iscsiadm:

```
# iscsiadm -V
iscsiadm version 6.2.0-873.13.el6
```

What syntax can I use to discover new iSCSI devices?

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax works for me for discovering new iSCSI devices. Note the extra `-D` parameter:

```
# iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 255.255.255.255 -D
255.255.255.255:3260,1035 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:foobar
255.255.255.255:3260,1036 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:foobar
255.255.255.255:3260,1037 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:foobar
255.255.255.255:3260,1034 iqn.1992-08.com.netapp:foobar
```

Comment: Glad worked for you,I'm just curious can you give try for this also "iscsiadm –m discovery –t st –p 255.255.255.255"

Comment: That also gives me "Try `iscsiadm --help' for more information." and exit code 7.